# Appending a list to a list of lists using list comprehensions in Python 3.6

Tags: list, append, list-comprehension, python-3.6

I would be very thankful If you coould help me with this:

I have file and I'm reading and parsing it's lines. This lines are a list of strings and I'm changing those strings to floats and then, I append that list of floats to another list of lists so my code looks something like this:

```
for line in file:
    #parsing code...
    [lista_flot.append(float(number)) for number in line]
    lecturas.append(lista_flot)
```

but I would like to know if there's a way of appending those lists in a single line with list comprehensions to make it something like this:

```
for line in file:
    #parsin code...
    lecturas.append([lista_flot.append(float(number)) for number in line])
```

Also, why when I do that single line all the values turn to Nones?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is the method `.append` will modify the list that it acts on, but it returns a value of `None`. For a list comprehension, you need the actual value you want to append as the expression.

```
for line in file:
    #parsin code...
    lecturas.append([float(number) for number in line])
```